Scientists trapped underground with air running out
The movie had scientists trapped underground in some super deep research place.  They could communicate with the surface but there was no oxygen or food or water exchange.  So they knew they were going to run out of air in x hours, but the rescue would take until x+24 hours, and they would all die unless ONE of them died, so they spend most of the movie trying to figure out how to randomly and anonymously have one killed so they would all have a clean conscience and not be prosecutable.  
Of course right after one of them was killed (in a blamable way, if I remember correctly), the drill broke through, because the actual depth of the chamber was classified...
I saw this movie on TV late at night in 1983 (Friday of Columbus day weekend, in NYC).
Anyone?  Was it actually a TV show?

Possibly the Kraft Suspense Theatre episode Leviathan Five from 1964:

five scientists and a security guard are trapped in a scientific installation deep underground when the only elevator shaft collapses. Having calculated their air supply, they find that survival is only possible if one of their number dies. All agree to a lottery: each will draw a computer knob from a basket (?) and withdraw to a private office, having first placed the security guard's gun on a table in the central office area. Whoever gets the black knob will have the choice of either killing himself or one of the others. If he decides to kill one of the others, the gun is to be wiped of prints and replaced on the table. After the shot, all will wait for some minutes before coming out to see what has happened. 

The plot unfolds in flashbacks at court. The episode is available on Youtube, if you want to verify it.
